# binding a function to a button d3.js - cannot make buttons switch colors in scatterplot

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am trying to create a scatterplot that checks whether one attributes value is the same or different and then colors the datapoint in the scatterplot according to that. So far I have achieved it but I want to check between columns, ex. column 3 is checked against all the other columns but in 4 different ways. I am trying to add switches (buttons) so that when I click on one particular button it checks (column 3 and 4), another one that checks (column 3 and 5) etc.

this is how I check that in d3 code:

```
   if (button_goo.clicked === true){
        if (d.foo == "0" && d.goo == "0"){
                return "blue";
        }
        else if (d.foo == "1" && d.goo == "1"){
                        return "green";
        }
        else if (d.foo == "1" && d.goo == "0"){
                        return "red";
        } 
        else if (d.foo == "0" && d.goo == "1"){
                        return "violet";
        }
     }
    else if(button_bar.clicked === true){
        if (d.foo == "0" && d.goo == "0"){
                return "blue";
        }
        else if (d.foo == "1" && d.goo == "1"){
                        return "green";
        }
        else if (d.foo == "1" && d.goo == "0"){
                        return "red";
        } 
        else if (d.foo == "0" && d.goo == "1"){
                        return "violet";
        }
    }
    else if(button_boo.clicked === true){
        if (d.foo == "0" && d.goo == "0"){
                return "blue";
        }
        else if (d.foo == "1" && d.goo == "1"){
                        return "green";
        }
        else if (d.foo == "1" && d.goo == "0"){
                        return "red";
        } 
        else if (d.foo == "0" && d.goo == "1"){
                        return "violet";
        }
    }
```

I know it's not beautiful because if I have more columns I would need to repeat this many times. But my main problem is that when I click the buttons, nothing happens. I have checked my code and I can't locate the problem.
This is the whole code in [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nhv9qj37/1/)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I change your code structure.

It seems you don't understand d3 update pattern.

all working example is here https://scrimba.com/c/cv8wD7H2

```
var dataSet = [
    {hour: "0.1",yval: "0.2",foo: "0", goo:"0", bar:"1", boo:"0"}, 
    {hour: "14",yval: "0.4",foo: "0", goo:"1", bar:"0", boo:"0"}, 
    {hour: "15",yval: "0.3",foo: "0", goo:"0", bar:"0", boo:"1"}, 
    {hour: "19",yval: "241",foo: "0", goo:"0", bar:"0", boo:"0"},
    {hour: "22",yval: "0.2",foo: "0", goo:"0", bar:"1", boo:"1"},
    {hour: "08",yval: "118",foo: "1", goo:"0", bar:"1", boo:"0"},
    {hour: "22",yval: "48",foo: "0", goo:"1", bar:"0", boo:"1"},
    {hour: "21",yval: "31",foo: "1", goo:"0", bar:"1", boo:"1"},
    {hour: "12",yval: "38",foo: "0", goo:"1", bar:"0", boo:"0"},
    {hour: "16",yval: "138",foo: "1", goo:"1", bar:"0", boo:"0"},
    {hour: "05",yval: "344",foo: "0", goo:"1", bar:"1", boo:"1"},
    {hour: "08",yval: "218",foo: "0", goo:"0", bar:"1", boo:"0"},
    {hour: "03",yval: "18",foo: "1", goo:"0", bar:"0", boo:"0"},
    {hour: "18",yval: "98",foo: "1", goo:"0", bar:"0", boo:"1"},
    {hour: "18",yval: "98",foo: "0", goo:"1", bar:"1", boo:"0"},
];

const COLOR_SET = {
    "goo": {
        "0:0": "blue",
        "1:1": "green",
        "1:0": "red",
        "0:1": "violet"
    },
    "bar": {
        "0:0": "green",
        "1:1": "red",
        "1:0": "violet",
        "0:1": "blue"
    },
    "boo": {
        "0:0": "red",
        "1:1": "violet",
        "1:0": "blue",
        "0:1": "green"
    }
}

function getColorByColorSet(colorSetName) {
    return function(data) {
        try {
            return COLOR_SET[colorSetName][ data.foo +':'+data.goo ]    
        }catch(e) {
            console.error(colorSetName, data)
            throw e;
        }   
    }
}

function MyScatterPlot(options={}) {
    var {w=500,h=500,top_pad=20,left_pad=100,target='body',dataSet=[],colorSetName='goo'} = options;
    this.dataSet = dataSet;
    this.colorSetName = colorSetName;

    // prepare
    this.xScale = d3.scale.linear()
        .domain([-1, 23])
        .range([left_pad, w - left_pad])

    this.yScale = d3.scale.linear()
        .domain([0, 350])
        .range([h - top_pad, top_pad]);

    this.svg = d3.select("body")
        .append("svg:svg")
        .attr("width", w + left_pad)
        .attr("height", h + top_pad);

    this.symbolTypes = {
        "circle": d3.svg.symbol().type("circle")
    };

    var fooColors = d3.scale.linear().domain([0, 50]).range(["#87CEFF", "#0000FF"]);
    var xAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(this.xScale).orient("bottom");
    var yAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(this.yScale).orient("left");

    this.svg.append("g")
        .attr("class", "axis")
        .attr("transform", "translate(0, " + (h - top_pad) + ")")
        .call(xAxis);

    this.svg.append("g")
        .attr("class", "axis")
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + (left_pad) + ", 0)")
        .call(yAxis);

    // end of prepare    
}

MyScatterPlot.prototype.changeColorSet = function(selectedColorsetName) {
    this.colorSetName = selectedColorsetName;
    this.svg.selectAll("path.dot")
        .style("fill", getColorByColorSet(this.colorSetName))    
}


MyScatterPlot.prototype.setData = function(dataSet) {   
    this.dataSet = dataSet

    let allDots = this.svg.selectAll("path.dot").data(this.dataSet)

    allDots.exit().remove();

    allDots.enter().append("path")
        .attr("class", "dot")
        .attr("d", (d,i)=>{return this.symbolTypes.circle();})


    allDots.attr("transform", (d) => {
        return  "translate(" + (this.xScale(d.hour) + (Math.random() * 12 - 6)) + "," +  this.yScale(d.yval) + ")"; 
    }).style("fill", getColorByColorSet(this.colorSetName))    
}

var scatterChart = new MyScatterPlot()
scatterChart.setData(dataSet)

let myUpdateFunction = function(clickedButtonName)  {    
    console.log('clickedButtonName : ' + clickedButtonName)
    scatterChart.changeColorSet(clickedButtonName)
}
```

===
here is another answer for your comment.
you need only on colorset. change color set like this

```
const COLOR_SET = {
            "0:0": "blue",
            "1:1": "green",
            "1:0": "red",
            "0:1": "violet"
}
```

and then
change getColorByColorSet() function as you want.

`colorSetName` parameter actually has clicked button name. so can not be removed just change parameter name to `clickedButton`

```
    function getColorByColorSet(clickedButton) {
    return function(data) {
        var finalColor;
        try { 
            if(clickedButton === 'goo') {
               finalColor = COLOR_SET[ data['bar']+':'+data['boo']]    
            }else if(clickedButton === 'bar'){
               finalColor = COLOR_SET[ data['goo']+':'+data['boo']]    
            }else if(clickedButton === 'boo'){
               finalColor = COLOR_SET[ data['goo']+':'+data['bar']] 
            }
            return finalColor

        }catch(e) {
            console.error(colorSetName, data)
            throw e;
        }   
    }
```

Comment: thank you for your help, but unfortunately this is not working. I thought it was going to work because it seemed right, but you have put different colors for the different columns, they need to be the same, they change based on the values 1:1/1:0/0:0/0:1

Comment: you can change getColorByColorSet() function's implementation as you wish. that function knows . 'data' and which button is pressed. you can copy and paste your nested if logic into getColorByColorSet() function  :)

Comment: Yes I change your nested IF statement because your nested if code do same thing wether which button is clicked. So I change color to check which button pressed. if Your "nested if statement" is correct then "outer If statement" is not needed.